# Replace .main-container with the overlaying element

Tags: php, function, background-image, overlay, element

Good evening

My site is skaipatras.gr

I want a background ad to appear complete on 100% of the browser like on site pelop.gr.

I am using Advanced Ads.

They say that I can move the background to another element using the code below in the functions.php file of your theme.

`add_filter( 'advanced-ads-pro-background-selector', 'my_custom_background_selector' ); function my_custom_background_selector(){ return '.main-container'; }`

But they have a note which says that I need to replace .main-container with the overlaying element.

Can someone please help me understand where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

I am the one who wrote the manual about the [background ads](https://wpadvancedads.com/manual/background-skin-ads-placement/). It was intended for developers, but maybe this short intro helps. The code you referred to is needed when the background is covered by another element.

Go to your site and right-click on the area where you would like the background ad to appear. Then click on "inspect". That should open the developer console in your browser, highlighting the HTML element that is covering that space.

Look at the HTML element to see if it has an `id` or `class` attribute. E.g., `<div id="container" class="grid-1 block">`.

If there is an `id` then replace `.main-container` in your code with the value + `#`. So in my example, that would be `#container`.

If there are only classes then you can use them. E.g., `.grid-1` or, if there are multiple classes `.grid-1.block`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong and every time I'm trying to put the code I destroy my site ..... Hehehehe

So I will try the All Access solution with Sticky Ads in it.

Comment: If your server crashes then there might be an issue with the code you copied. If the changed background is breaking your layout then it is likely that your theme is not compatible with the feature and using Sticky Ads sounds like a great solution.